# How do I select a value from a drop down list in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the font of an aside, when you select the font you want to use from a drop down list.

However, the only value my code will pick up is for the first option of the list. When I click on another font, nothing happens. How do I get the other values selected? Thank you.

```js
var fontVal = $("select option").attr("value");

alert(fontVal);

function fontChoice(){
 if(fontVal == "Choose"){
  $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"sans-serif"});
  console.log('Choose');
 }else if(fontVal == "Arial"){
  $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"Arial"});
  console.log('Courier');
 }else if(fontVal == "Times"){
  $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"Times New Roman"});
  console.log('Times');
 }else if(fontVal == "Impact"){
  $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"Impact"});
  console.log('Impact');
 }else if(fontVal == "Courier"){
  $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"Courier"});
  console.log('Courier');
 };
};

fontChoice();
```

```html
<aside id="mirror">
</aside>
<select id="fonts">
 <option value="Choose">Choose your font</option>
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Times">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
    <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s9v4mvfv/

Comment: You need to bind your function to the change event of the select element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `change` event of the `select` to get the selected value.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#fonts').on('change', function(){

        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case 'Choose':
                $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"sans-serif"});
                break;
            case 'Arial':
                $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"Arial"});
                break;
            case 'Times':
                $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"Times New Roman"});
                break;
            case 'Impact':
                $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"Impact"});
                break;
            case 'Courier':
                $('#mirror').css({"font-family":"Courier"});
                break;            
        }

    });
});
```

Here's a working **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9v4mvfv/1/)**.

Comment: This was perfect!! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: great. please mark this as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Just had to take out case 4 :P

Comment: oh sorry about that. didn't notice it. ;)

Comment: updated my answer. please accept it if it helped you.

Comment: Gotta wait one more minute :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a switch statement looks like overkill to me. Also you have the full font names in the option elements. You can also take advantage of the ternary operator to reduce your code to one line.

```js
$('#fonts').on('change', function() {
    $('#mirror').css({ 
        "font-family": this.value.trim() == 'Choose' ? 
        'sans-serif' : $('option:selected', this).text() 
    });
});
```

```css
.demo {
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <aside id="mirror" class="demo">
      Sample Text
 </aside>
 <select id="fonts">
  <option value="Choose">Choose your font</option>
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Times">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
    <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: your answer is the shortest and better than mine.

Comment: Would be glad to receive your vote :-) Thanks. Yours is correct too. @Sushil

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fontChoice() {
  var fontVal = $("select").find(':selected').val();

  alert(fontVal);


  if (fontVal == "Choose") {
    $('#mirror').css({
      "font-family": "sans-serif"
    });
    console.log('Choose');
  } else if (fontVal == "Arial") {
    $('#mirror').css({
      "font-family": "Arial"
    });
    console.log('Courier');
  } else if (fontVal == "Times") {
    $('#mirror').css({
      "font-family": "Times New Roman"
    });
    console.log('Times');
  } else if (fontVal == "Impact") {
    $('#mirror').css({
      "font-family": "Impact"
    });
    console.log('Impact');
  } else if (fontVal == "Courier") {
    $('#mirror').css({
      "font-family": "Courier"
    });
    console.log('Courier');
  };


};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<aside id="mirror">
</aside>
<select id="fonts" onchange="fontChoice();">
  <option value="Choose">Choose your font</option>
  <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="Times">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
  <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
</select>
```

You should be using `$("select").find(':selected').val();` Added in the select tag an onchange attribute